# how to reference xsd file from xml

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

1) `pls.xsd` file

I have included `pls.xsd` in `xml.xsd` in same folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Externals changed by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->

<!--
  This is a draft schema for the XML language defined in the 
  Pronunciation Lexicon Specification 
  (latest version at <http://www.w3.org/TR/pronunciation-lexicon/>)
  At the time of writing, the specification as well as this schema are
  subject to change, and no guarantee is made on their accuracy or the fact
  that they are in sync.
  Last modified: $Date: 2007/12/11 12:08:40 $

  Copyright û 2006 World Wide Web Consortium, (Massachusetts Institute
  of Technology, ERCIM, Keio University). All Rights Reserved. See
    http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Legal/.
-->
<xs:schema
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:p="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon"
elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0">
<xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>Importing dependent namespaces</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="xml.xsd" />

 ...
</xs:schema>
```

2)My XML file
from this file i am referencing `pls.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<lexicon version="1.0"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2005/01/pronunciation-lexicon
file://C:/xsdforproject/pls.xsd" 
alphabet="x-microsoft-ups" xml:lang="en-IN">
    <lexeme>

    </lexeme>
</lexicon>
```

I have above two codes these giving me an errors in both my `XML` and in my `pls.xsd` file,
an error has occurred while opening external "DTD" `file:///C:/xsdforproject/XMLSchema.dtd': Could not find file 'C:\xsdforproject\XMLSchema.dtd`

I am using "Visual Studio 2010".

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that something you're using is referencing XMLSchema.dtd, so have you tried downloading it and placing it in your xsdforproject folder?

http://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.dtd